# Group numbers by tolerance

Tags: r

I have sample dataset like this (where each number represents a time in minutes):

```
d <- list(c(1.583, 2.433, 4.883, 5.533, 6.283), c(1.6, 1.605, 5.05, 
5.517, 6.05), c(0.283, 0.833, 1.5, 2.383, 3.317), c(1.6, 2.133, 
3.35, 4.983))
```

What I want to do is group together numbers that are close to each other (+/- tolerance, for instance 0.25 minutes). The rules to this are:

- A element (time-point in a list) can only belong to **one** group. This means that in list 2, that 1.6 and 1.605 should be considered part of different groups.
- Each group can have from 1 to n elements in them, where n is the number of sub-lists in d, in this case 4
- There's no guarantee that the lists are of same length

For instance I would expect `1.583 list 1`, `1.6 list 2` and `1.6 list 4` to form a group, event though 1.605 from list 2 would fit in the range 1.594 +/- 0.25 it's not considered part of the groups since 1.6 from this list is already assigned.

I've tried googling for a solution but I haven't found anything of use. I don't know if it's because of bad terminology or because there isn't one standard way of doing this.

I know this is a hard problem to solve but is there any R package that deals with this type of problem?

Comment: I mean the number of sub-lists, I'll try to make this clearer in the description

Comment: This sounds akin to nearest neighbour analysis. I'm not sure if it would work entirely for your situation, but you can try to use `get.knn` from the `FNN` package. However, for this to work, you would have to be able to define a maximum number of nearest neighbours you want to find for each data point.

Comment: If 2 or more grouping are possible (like in you example), what is your policy to decide? The distance? What if they are equally close?

Comment: @prolix Then either one of them can be chosen. Yes, preferably the distance is used to decide, the grouping is done in such a way that distance within groups is minimized. kneijenhuijs I'll have a look at this package, thanks!